# Javascript object query

Tags: javascript, object

not sure if an object is what I want but I want to create something like this.

```
var thing = {a: 0, b: 0};
function fun () {
    var mything = new thing();
    mything.a = 5;
    mything.b = 7;
    return mything;
}
var another = fun();
```

and then i could use another.a and another.b in my code. I am working in javascript and am fairly new to this. I know in another languages I would create a struct but not sure how to go about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you want because now I am not understanding you.

Answer (score 0):

`thing` in your example is an object but not a function. You cannot call it as a function.

For the purposes of your example, all you need `mything` to be is an object. So:

```
var mything = {};
```

If you want to create a constructor and use inheritance, then see [MDN's documentation on **constructor functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) or, if you want to use ES6, [the documentation on **Classes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Answer (score 0):

I believe `function` is what you want. Please review this one:

```js
function thing() {
  if (!(this instanceof thing)) {
    return new thing();
  }
  //properties with default value
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 7;
  return this;
}

//and you can call it either like this
var foo = thing();
//or like this
var bar = new thing();

//and both you can define their dependent property like this
foo.a = 123;
foo.b = 345;

bar.a = "not number1";
bar.b = {
  other: "result"
}
console.log(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `Thing` using class syntax (ES6) or function  constructor:

```
// Using ES6 syntax

class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 7;
  }

  foo() {
    // thing instance method (`this` === current instance)
  }
}

// OR Using classic constructor syntax

function Thing() {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 7;
}

Thing.prototype.foo = function() {
  // thing instance method (`this` === current instance)
};
```

And after you can create/allocate new instances using `new`:

```
var thing = new Thing();
```

Or well wrap it using a factory method, for example:

```
// ES6 syntax
class Thing {
  // ...
  static create() {
    return new Thing();
  }
}

// Or attaching to Thing
Thing.create = function factory() {
  return new Thing();
}
```

And calling it:

```
var things = Thing.create();
```